# USMT script is failing with Return Code 71

Tags: windows, powershell, usmt

I am working on a USMT script for profile migrations and running into an issue where when I try and use scanstate.exe it will exit with code 71 - "Unable to start. Make sure you are running USMT with elevated privileges"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-return-codes#bkmk-returncodes

Per the above site, the fix is to exit USMT and run with elevated permissions. Well, I am running this off a management server that I am logged into with my domain admin account and running powershell as an administrator and still getting this error message. I really don't understand why I am getting it.

Here is the script I am using:

```
#Import-Module -Name 'P:\Information Technology\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Modules\Write-Log' -Verbose

$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
     'Write-Log:Label' = 'USMT'
}

function Invoke-USMT {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$SourceComputer,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$DestinationComputer,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$UserName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$SharePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$USMTFilesPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Domain,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage='Enter USMT key')]
        [Security.SecureString]$SecureKey,
        [pscredential]$Credential
    )
    
    begin 
    {
        #Test source and destination computers are online
        Write-Host 'Begin function'
        Write-Host 'Attempting to ping source computer'
        if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $SourceComputer -Count 2 -ErrorAction Continue))
        {
            Write-Host 'Ping to source computer failed'
            #Write-Log -Message "Count not ping $SourceComputer" -Level "Warning" -File
            Break
        } else {
            Write-Host 'Success'
        }
        Write-Host 'Attempting to ping destination computer'
         if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $DestinationComputer -Count 2 -ErrorAction Continue))
        {
            Write-Host 'Ping to destination computer failed'
            #Write-Log -Message "Count not ping $DestinationComputer" -Level "Warning" -File
            Break
        } else {
            Write-Host 'Success'
        }
    }
    
    process 
    {
        #Copy USMT files to remote computers
        Try 
        {
            Write-Host 'Attempting to copy USMT files to source computer'
            #Write-Log -Message "Attempting to copy USMT files to source computer" -File
            Copy-Item -Path $USMTFilesPath -Destination "\\$SourceComputer\C$\USMTFiles" -ErrorAction Stop -Recurse -force -con
            Write-Host 'Attempting to copy USMT files to destination computer'
            #Write-Log -Message "Attempting to copy USMT files to destination computer" -File
            Copy-Item -Path $USMTFilesPath -Destination "\\$DestinationComputer\C$\USMTFiles" -ErrorAction Stop -Recurse -force
        }
        Catch 
        {
            Write-Host $_ + ' - Error'
            #Write-Log -Message '$_' -Level "Error" -File
            Break
        }
        #Enable CredSSP
        Write-Host 'Invoking CredSSP on source computer & passing credentials'
        #Write-Log -Message "Enabling CredSSP on source computer" -File
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceComputer -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server -Force}
        Write-Host 'Invoking CredSSP on destination computer & passing credentials'
        #Write-Log -Message "Enabling CredSSP on destination computer" -File
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DestinationComputer -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server -Force} 
        Write-Host 'Enabling CredSSP on source computer'
        Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer $SourceComputer -Force
        Write-Host 'Enabling CredSSP on destination computer'
        Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer $DestinationComputer -Force 
        
        #Start startscan on source
        Write-Host 'Starting startscan on source computer & passing credentials'
        #Write-Log -Message "Starting startscan on source computer" -File
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceComputer -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credential -Scriptblock {
            $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Using:SecureKey)
            $Key = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
            c:\USMTFiles\scanstate.exe "$Using:SharePath\$Using:Username" /i:c:\usmtfiles\printers.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\custom.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migdocs.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migapp.xml /v:13 /ui:$Using:Domain\$Using:UserName /c /localonly /encrypt /key:$Key /listfiles:c:\usmtfiles\listfiles.txt /ue:pcadmin /ue:$Using:Domain\*
        } -ArgumentList {$UserName,$SharePath,$SecureKey,$SourceComputer,$Domain}
#
        #Start loadscan on destination
        Write-Host 'Starting loanscan on destination computer  passing credentials'
        #Write-Log -Message "Starting loadscan on destination computer" -File
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DestinationComputer -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credential -Scriptblock {
            $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Using:SecureKey)
            $Key = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
            c:\USMTFiles\loadstate.exe "$Using:SharePath\$Using:Username" /i:c:\usmtfiles\printers.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\custom.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migdocs.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migapp.xml /v:13 /ui:$Using:Domain\$Using:username /c /decrypt /key:$Key
        } -ArgumentList {$UserName,$SharePath,$SecureKey,$DestinationComputer,$Domain}

        #Remove USMT files on remote computers
        Write-Host 'Removing USMT files from source computer'
        #Write-Log -Message "Removing USMT files from source computer" -File
        Remove-Item \\$SourceComputer\C$\USMTFiles -Force -Recurse
        Write-Host 'Removing USMT files from destination computer'
        #Write-Log -Message "Removing USMT files from destination computer" -File
        Remove-Item \\$DestinationComputer\C$\USMTFiles -Force -Recurse

        #Disable CredSSP on remote computers
        Write-Host 'Disabling CredSSP on source computer'
        #Write-Log -Message "Disabling CredSSP on source computer" -File
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceComputer -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role server }
        Write-Host 'Disabling CredSSP on destination computer'
        #Write-Log -Message "Disabling CredSSP on destination computer" -File
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DestinationComputer -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role server }  
        Write-Host 'Disabling CredSSP on client'
        Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role client        
     }
}
```

And this is the part where I get the error

```
 #Start startscan on source
        Write-Host 'Starting startscan on source computer & passing credentials'
        #Write-Log -Message "Starting startscan on source computer" -File
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceComputer -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credential -Scriptblock {
            $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Using:SecureKey)
            $Key = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
            c:\USMTFiles\scanstate.exe "$Using:SharePath\$Using:Username" /i:c:\usmtfiles\printers.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\custom.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migdocs.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migapp.xml /v:13 /ui:$Using:Domain\$Using:UserName /c /localonly /encrypt /key:$Key /listfiles:c:\usmtfiles\listfiles.txt /ue:pcadmin /ue:$Using:Domain\*
        } -ArgumentList {$UserName,$SharePath,$SecureKey,$SourceComputer,$Domain}
```

I have made sure that Enable-PSRemoting -Force has been done on both source and destination computer and I also made sure to enable "Allow delegating fresh credentials" in the group policy for the management server, the source computer, & the destination computer along with adding "WSMAN/*.domain.com" to the server list.

I have done quite a bit of searching online and cross checking with team members but we are out of ideas on this one. Hoping you guys have some insight.

The error in powershell:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the scriptblock you use the variables from outside with `$using:`, you do not need to send them using the  `-ArgumentList`parameter.
If you do want to do that, add a `param()` block in the scriptblock and remove the `using:` scope modifier for the variables.

BTW, `-ArgumentList` takes an array of values, not a scriptblock, and I have left out the `$SourceComputer` variable in the second example because the scriptblock doesn't use it.

Try either this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceComputer -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credential -Scriptblock {
    $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Using:SecureKey)
    $Key = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
    c:\USMTFiles\scanstate.exe "$Using:SharePath\$Using:Username" /i:c:\usmtfiles\printers.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\custom.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migdocs.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migapp.xml /v:13 /ui:$Using:Domain\$Using:UserName /c /localonly /encrypt /key:$Key /listfiles:c:\usmtfiles\listfiles.txt /ue:pcadmin /ue:$Using:Domain\*
}
```

or:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceComputer -Authentication Credssp -Credential $Credential -Scriptblock {
    param(
        $UserName,
        $SharePath,
        $SecureKey,
        $Domain
    )
    $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecureKey)
    $Key = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
    c:\USMTFiles\scanstate.exe "$SharePath\$Username" /i:c:\usmtfiles\printers.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\custom.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migdocs.xml /i:c:\usmtfiles\migapp.xml /v:13 /ui:$Domain\$UserName /c /localonly /encrypt /key:$Key /listfiles:c:\usmtfiles\listfiles.txt /ue:pcadmin /ue:$Domain\*
} -ArgumentList $UserName,$SharePath,$SecureKey,$Domain
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with the second set there and this fixed my issue and worked perfectly!

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the nice feedback!